# how to pass an object from a function to a component in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of objects created with "FlatList" and when I click an element I would go to a page via "navigation" and show the values.
In the Ordine component I try to print but it returns an error.

```
export default class ItemComponent extends Component {
    //handling onPress action  
    getListViewItem = (item) => {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Ordine', { otherParam: 'Ordine' });
        return (
            <Ordine item={item} />
        );
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false} contentContainerStyle={{
                flexGrow:
                    1, centerContent: true, paddingBottom: Constants.statusBarHeight
            }}>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.props.items}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.getListViewItem.bind(this,
                        item, this.props.navigation)} activeOpacity={1} >
                        <Item item={item} />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                    }
                    ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
                />
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
}
```

Ordine Component

```
export default class Ordine extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flexDirection: 'row',
                    height: 100,
                    padding: 20,
                }}>
                <Text>{this.props.item.Nome}</Text>
                <Text>text</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

When I click an element it returns the error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.item.Nome')

Comment: Did you mean to write `<Text>{this.props.item.name}</Text>` ? you code has `<Text>{this.props.item.Nome}</Text>` this could be the reason for the error.

Comment: items is array of object with this values: Nome , cognome , Totale created like this: `{Nome:doc.data().Nome,Cognome:doc.data().Cognome,Totale:doc.data().Totale}`

Comment: If it's an array, you need to map through the object using the `map()` function. if it's a single object, you can use `this.props.item[0].Nome`

Comment: I found my mistake: to pass a parameter from one component to another when using "navigation" you must use routes `this.props.navigation.navigate ('Order', {otherParam: 'Order', item: item}) ;` only this way Order component will have the "item" parameter

Comment: You can `console.log(this.props.item)` to see what type of object is returned.